# Cannot install tensorflow on raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi3

I am running into an error when I try to install tensorflow using pip on my raspberry pi 3b+.

Here is the error message:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-p4UFOu/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ofsmSC/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-p4UFOu/h5py/
```

Here is the command I tried that gave the error I mentioned:

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

I am running the latest version of Raspbian OS and have updated and upgraded my raspberry pi. I am also using python 2.7 and this works successfully with python 2.7 on my ubuntu 18.10 laptop.

Any ideas how I can successfully do this?

Comment: Actually, disregard my previous comments as `tensorflow` is still available via piwheels. Can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: Wild guess - judging by the line you provided, it's the `h5py` package failing to build - check whether you have the `hdf5` headers installed. If not, issue `sudo apt install libhdf5-dev` and then retry `pip install tensorflow`. If this doesn't help, add the complete error trace to the question.

Comment: @hoeflinghow please make your comment and answer so j can accept it. This was the right answer. And it runs on Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing by `/tmp/pip-install-p4UFOu/h5py/setup.py`, you have the issues with installing the `h5py` package which is required by `tensorflow`. Since you are building `h5py` from source (the prebuilt ARM wheels exist for Python 3.4/3.5 only atm), refer to the [`h5py` installation docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#source-installation):

> To install h5py from source, you need three things installed:
>
> - A supported Python version with development headers
> - HDF5 1.8.4 or newer with development headers
> - A C compiler

On Raspbian and Python 2, this translates to:

- `apt install python-dev`
- `apt install libhdf5-dev`
- `apt install gcc` (or, if you want the whole development tools to be installed at once, `apt install build-essential`)

Now `pip install h5py` should have everything to build and install the package properly.